# Trait 'Spatie\MediaLibrary\HasMedia\HasMediaTrait' not found

Tags: php, laravel

It show the error which can't get the namespace for HasMedia(red color font) and undefined class for HasMediaTrait(on line 16) , any ideas?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you have installed the package?

Comment: May I know how to install it ?

Comment: composer require spatie/laravel-medialibrary:^7.0.0
More on their docs :
 https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-medialibrary/v7/installation-setup

Comment: is seen like version not support. Because I using 5.1. So Is that anyway to install it without upgrade the version ?

Comment: You would need to install an older version of medialibrary that's compatible with such an old version of Laravel

Comment: alright. is works!

Comment: composer install !