# Laravel 7 : Interface 'Spatie\MediaLibrary\HasMedia' not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, laravel-medialibrary

I have this error while using the MediaLibrary package

```
Interface 'Spatie\MediaLibrary\HasMedia' not found
Trait 'Spatie\MediaLibrary\InteractsWithMedia' not found
```

My project details :-

php : 7.3.22

laravel : 7.28.3

I have tried follow the documentation v7 and also run the command below

```
composer require spatie/laravel-medialibrary
```

Other than that, I have also checked on other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52896708/trait-spatie-medialibrary-hasmedia-hasmediatrait-not-found#) which I have follow most of the steps but still getting back the same error

**composer.json**

```
"require": {
        "php": "^7.2.5",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.2",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^1.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
        "laravel/framework": "^7.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
        "laravelcollective/html": "^6.2",
        "spatie/laravel-activitylog": "^3.16",
        "spatie/laravel-medialibrary": "^7.19"
    },
```

**Model**

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Spatie\Activitylog\Traits\LogsActivity;
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\HasMedia;
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\InteractsWithMedia;
class Applicant extends Model implements HasMedia
{
    use LogsActivity, InteractsWithMedia;
}
```

Comment: Try with regenerate classes `composer dump-autoload`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Make sure to follow the documentation for the specific version of Laravel-medialibrary that you are using. In your case [version 7](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-medialibrary/v7/basic-usage/preparing-your-model#breadcrumb). It looks like you were following the [version 8](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-medialibrary/v8/basic-usage/preparing-your-model#breadcrumb) documentation.

In version 7, the trait is `Spatie\MediaLibrary\HasMedia\HasMediaTrait` instead of `Spatie\MediaLibrary\InteractsWithMedia`. And the interface is `Spatie\MediaLibrary\HasMedia\HasMedia` instead of `Spatie\MediaLibrary\HasMedia`.

If you want to use version 8 instead, change your requirements to `"spatie/laravel-medialibrary": "^8.0"` and then run `composer update`.

Comment: Thanks sir, it solves the problem, I have accepted this as the answer